# C# Socket to receive UDP packets with some pause periods

Tags: c#

I have tried to run a C# (.Net 4.8) program to receive UDP packets from my server. The packets are sent frequently (about 20ms per packet), with about 100 bytes per packet.

My program can receive them normally. However, after received for about 100-200 packets, it fails to receive for about 3 seconds, thus quite a lot of packets are missed. I have counted that if we have sent 1000 packets, only around 600-700 packets can be received.

However, if I stop the client side program, I can see from Wireshark that my PC can receive packets smoothly without any pauses.

My code is similar as follows:

```
internal class StateObject
{
   internal Socket workSocket = null;
   internal const int BufferSize = 300;
   internal byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
}

private void Connect()
{
   IPAddress objIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(mstrServername);
   mobjIPEndPointUdp = new IPEndPoint(objIPAddress, miUdpPort);
   mobjUdpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
   mobjUdpSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = 0x10000;
   mobjUdpSocket.Connect(mobjIPEndPointUdp);

   // Create a new thread to call RecvUdpFunc to receive UDP packets...
}

private void RecvUdpFunc()
{
   byte[] arb = null;
   try
   {
      StateObject state = new StateObject();
      state.workSocket = mobjUdpSocket;
      mobjUdpSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref mobjEndPointUdp, new AsyncCallback(RecvUdp), state);
   }
   catch
   {

   }
}

private void RecvUdp(IAsyncResult result)
{
   byte[] arb = null;

   try
   {
      StateObject state = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
      Socket client = state.workSocket;
      int bytes = client.EndReceiveFrom(result, ref mobjEndPointUdp);

      client.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref mobjEndPointUdp, new AsyncCallback(RecvUdp), state);
      if (bytes > 0)
      {
         arb = new byte[bytes];
         Array.Copy(state.buffer, arb, bytes);
         // Process the object arb by queuing it to another thread...
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

   }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there might be a race condition in `Array.Copy(state.buffer, arb, bytes);` whilst  `BeginReceiveFrom` is asynchronously using `state.buffer`. Maybe move that whole if block before `BeginReceiveFrom`.

Comment: 300 bytes is kinda small for a network receive buffer  - it's also not a power-of-2 so it's probably suboptimal - normally you should size it to be a multiple of 4096. Consider using a 65535 byte (i.e. 64KB-sized) buffer as that matches UDP's maximum datagram length.

Comment: You **must not** have an empty `catch` blocks - it means you're swallowing-exceptions, and that could be the reason why it's not working.

Comment: I have tried to put the BeginReceiveFrom line after the if (bytes > 0) block. Also, the buffer is changed to 4096 and try catch block are removed. The situation seems to improved a bit but still far from expectation.

Comment: I have just tried to disable the line "mobjUdpSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(..." in function RecvUdpFunc, i.e., not receive any packet in my program, and just monitor the packet flow using Wireshark. I found that it does pause similar to my program. It seems it is a problem for Windows or my hardware? I think it is strange as I don't think it is only my problem.